# using Regex Constant to return string between two tags

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to use in C#

```
 var added = Regex.Match(Text,
 "\[BEGINTAG\](.+?)\[\/ENDTAG\]",RegexOptions.None);
```

to return the string between the tags [BEGINTAG] and [/ENDTAG] in a text string. I can't figure out what's wrong with my regex constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is good. You just need to extract group 1 (the thing you match between parenthesis)

In C# this becomes

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\[BEGINTAG\](.+?)\[/ENDTAG\]");
resultString = regexObj.Match(subjectString).Groups[1].Value;
```

Let me know if this works

Also, FYI, you don't need to escape as much as you do. This is also good:

```
\[BEGINTAG](.+?)\[/ENDTAG]
```

Comment: If you are interested in performance it's good to know that \[BEGINTAG]([^[]*)\[/ENDTAG] does not require any backtracking and is expected to be perform better.

Answer (score 1):

One possible problem is that you don't have a `@` before your string, so C# is treating the `\` characters as C# escapes rather than regex escapes.

Buckley's answer shows how to prefix the string with `@` so that the `\` are handled as regex escapes. It's almost always better to use this format for regex in C#. Otherwise you end up with something like this.

```
var added = Regex.Match(Text, 
    "\\[BEGINTAG\\](.+?)\\]\\/ENDTAG\\]", RegexOptions.None);
```

Which I find hard to read.